# Problema con calendario al recuperar eventos [JS]

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

estoy creando esta pregunta porque ya no se que hacer, he mirado bastante, he cambiado el código bastantes veces y sigo sin hallar solución alguna.

Pongo en contexto, estoy haciendo un calendario en html, css y js, y ahora estoy conectándolo a una base de datos en localhost, a la hora de crear eventos los crea y los guarda perfectamente, el problema está en que no consigo hacer que "pinte" los eventos que recibe, lo más lejos que he llegado ha sido haciendo que cuando pase al mes siguiente, al regresar me aparezcan todos los eventos guardados en un mismo día, obviamente eso no es lo que quiero, os comparto por aquí mi función que uso para recibir los eventos

```
function requestDB() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "../../php/calendario/calendarioGetEvents2.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      $.each(response, function(index, object){
        var date = object.fecha;
        var nombre = object.nombre;
        var timeFrom = object.horaInicio;
        var timeTo = object.horaFin; 
        var dayDate = date.split('-')[2];
        var monthDate = date.split('-')[1];
        var yearDate = date.split('-')[0];
        newEvent = {
          title: nombre,
          time: timeFrom + " - " + timeTo,
        };
        if (eventsArr.length > 0) {
          eventsArr.forEach((item) => {
            if (
              dayDate=== activeday &&
              monthDate === month + 1 &&
              yearDate === year
            ) {
              item.events.push(newEvent);
              eventAdded = true;
            }
          });
        }
      
        if (!eventAdded) {
          eventsArr.push({
            day: activeday,
            month: month + 1,
            year: year,
            events: [newEvent],
          });
        }
      })
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
  });
}
```

Adjunto también un pastebin con todo el código js por si acaso necesitarais más información
https://pastebin.com/8jKY2GxR

Comment: Te falta agregar la llamada a `initCalendar`

Comment: Donde lo tendria que añadir? en la de requestDb?

Comment: Supongo que después de ` $.each(response, function(index, object){....})` dentro del `success`

Comment: No me lo ha solucionado, gracias por el intento de todas formas